# ASP.NET auth cookie and session ID not cleared when Chrome browser is closed

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, session, cookies, .aspxauth

I have a situation with both the .ASPXAUTH and ASP.NET_SessionId cookies not being cleared when the Chrome browser is closed, and not just the tab, but the entire browser and all browser windows.  This is not happening in IE and Firefox.

The auth cookie is set to not be persistent and the session ID cookie is also set to not persist.  No future expirations have been specified with either cookie and if I inspect the cookies under Chrome settings it clearly shows that expiration is set to when the browser session ends.

And as I said, this is not an issue in either IE or Firefox.  I've perused all the other StackOverflow threads on this issue, as well as other sites, and I've checked out all the obvious things that can be an issue with cookies.  I could add an ajax call on the browser close to call my action that does an explicit forms auth signout and session abandon, but that's a real pain and more of a hack in my opinion.  Besides, this should work as designed according to the cookie settings.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem with the help of a colleague.  Chrome is running in the background.  If I disabled this browser setting, everything works as it should.

I understand it makes sense for some web apps to run in the background, but from a security perspective it makes more sense if the only apps running in the background are the ones that are specified to do so, and not the entire browser.  I haven't looked into the settings for this in Chrome, but I think what should happen upon browser close is that for any apps not specified to run in the background the cookies should be cleared and everything else left intact for those apps that need to run in the background.  This way a browser close operates like a traditional browser close by default, and everything else can run in the background at will.